# Upload PDF file to my server from a remote server

Tags: php, pdf

I have the link to a PDF file from a remote server (A service sends me a link to my PDF invoice). Instead of saving the PDF file in my computer and then uploading the file to my server, I would like to have a link or form to save the file directly to my server. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `file_get_contents()`

Your code will look like this

```
//save pdf on server
$file = file_get_contents('https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/downloads/impatient-js-preview-book.pdf');
file_put_contents('impatient-js-preview-book.pdf', $file);
```

Pls don't forget to vote me up
thanks

Comment: Thank you for answering! Where do I add my server information?

Comment: Add the link as a parameter to the file_get_contents function. just as the sample I showed.